# Shut Down PC with textbox a timer

Tags: c#, shutdown

I want to shutdown pc by following command:

```
Process.Start("shutdown", string.Format(@"/s /t "+textBox1.Text+" /m \\{0}", txtPC.Text));
```

But it doesn't return the value for timer from textbox1.

Comment: What did you put in `textBox1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this (`@` doesn't apply to the second string literal containing `\\` and it will be interpreted by the compiler as a single `\`)

```
string.Format(@"/s /t {0} /m \\{1}", textBox1.Text, txtPC.Text);
```